# Rename [atlassian-stash] to [bitbucket-server]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request

Atlassian Stash has been renamed to Bitbucket Server. Can [atlassian-stash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/atlassian-stash) be renamed to [bitbucket-server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bitbucket-server), and perhaps set up as a synonym for the new tag?

https://www.atlassian.com/software/bitbucket/server

> Stash is now called Bitbucket Server

Comment: I would advise a synonym, just because Atlassian decided to rebrand the product does not mean that users don't know it by its former name.

Comment: Not to mention that there will be many questions about older versions, when it *was* called Atlassian Stash, where tagging them with [tag:bitbucket-server] would just be plain inaccurate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Done.

[bitbucket-server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bitbucket-server) is the master tag, since that's the official name of the product.

There was also an [atlassian-bitbucketserver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/atlassian-bitbucketserver) tag that had been created, so I merged that one in, as well.