# How can I suggest a tag synonym without 5 rep in the tag?

Tags: support, tags, tag-synonym-process

Whist reviewing an edit a user had edited the atlassian-stash tag to contain information stating that this product was [now known as bitbucket server](https://www.atlassian.com/software/bitbucket/server), but that he couldn't create the tag.

I [created the new tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/new/atlassian-bitbucketserver?show=all&sort=newest&pageSize=50), and thought that the [existing tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/new/atlassian-stash?show=all&sort=newest&pageSize=50) should be a synonym for it, but I can't suggest this as I don't have 5 score in the tag.

Is there some other procedure for this situation? Or should I have not created the new tag?

Comment: Ask on meta, if you cannot act yourself. Like you did just now.

Comment: You could also try a chat room for that language if there is an active one.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/306597/rename-atlassian-stash-to-bitbucket-server